# How to configure payment module Check/Money Order (not configured - needs pay-to)

Tags: zen-cart

I installed the payment option check/money order on the [Zen Cart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Cart) admin side, but it says

> Check/Money Order (not configured - needs pay-to)

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

In admin->modules->payment, select Check/Money order, hit the edit button on the right, and at the bottom on the right, put the name of the person to whom the check should be made payable.